# Run old Linux release in a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I've got a binary application that won't work on versions of Ubuntu later than Feisty.

Is it possible to build a Docker image containing Feisty and run it on my modern system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to build your own base image. I'm not aware of any reasons why it should not work.

Check out the documentation http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/baseimages/ for a starting point and keep us posted :)

Comment: Wow. It was actually super easy. Following the example at the link you gave I needed to add the path to the feisty repos like this: sudo debootstrap feisty feisty http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ but the resulting container starts and reports that it is feisty. Now to see if my old code runs. Thanks!

Comment: The link in your reply is not working anymore, I was not able to resolve it using the wayback machine. Can you please make it point to the proper part of the current Docker documentation?

Answer (score 10):

I'll add more detail than I am allowed in the comments. These are the steps I used to get a 32-bit release of Ubuntu Feisty working in a Docker 0.7.1 container.

```
cd /tmp
sudo debootstrap --arch=i386 feisty feisty http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
sudo tar -C feisty -c . | docker import - feisty
```

Now I have a 32-bit feisty base image. I banged out a Dockerfile and my ancient code appears to work correctly in the container.