# Are there any limitations regarding the age of a linux distribution which can be used to create a docker base-image?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

Im wondering if its possible to use very old Linux Distribution like Debian GNU/Linux 3.1 (Sarge) and create a base-image of it to run legacy code not working under "younger" distros.

Only Thing i found about it was somebody successfully using Ubuntu Feisty:  [Run old Linux release in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414036/run-old-linux-release-in-a-docker-container)

Are there any known limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Your host needs to have a minimal version of the Linux kernel, and that version is 3.10

See

[Docker minimum kernel version 3.8.13 or 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216191/docker-minimum-kernel-version-3-8-13-or-3-10)

extract from the previous link

`There's also a shell-script to check if your system has the required dependencies in place and to check which features are available;
https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh`

So you can use this to check if you will be able to use docker on this host.

From

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSarge?action=show&redirect=Sarge

I see

`kernel : linux 2.4.27 and 2.6.8`

So it may not work

Comment: Maybe i have to clarify: i dont want to install the docker engine in Debian GNU/Linux 3.1 (Sarge) and use this host to run Images there what would not be possible due to the reasons you listed.
My aim is to create a base Image out of a old distro and run this on what ever machine has a running docker engine.
Or is the kernel Limitation for the engine even valid for the createn of base-Images?

Comment: I see on `https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=ubuntu10&starCount=0` docker images based on Ubuntu 10, which is supposed to have a 2.6 kernel, according to `nhttps://askubuntu.com/questions/10308/what-kernel-version-comes-with-ubuntu-10-04-1`

Comment: Ok, thats something to start from but still lets space for try and error :/